# Trigger another button click from md-button Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a page (say a parent page) that contain `MdDialog` component. Inside the dialog window, I have set a `md-button`.
Can this `md-button` trigger the parent page button's function on click?

Comment: yes it can make use of shared services and trigger the action

Comment: why not creating  a standard controller which deals with page and dialog.

Comment: Can you give an example? Sorry I am fairly new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a subject to trigger an event. Use a shared service for emitting and subscribing to the subject.

Define a `shared.service` like this:

```
import {Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService{
   public triggerParentMethod: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
}
```

In your `ParentComponent`, subscribe to the `triggerParentMethod` in constructor:

```
constructor(private sharedService:SharedService,public dialog: MdDialog){
      this.sharedService.triggerParentMethod.subscribe( value =>{
        if(value == true){
          // Call some method here or some piece of code
          console.log('called from dialog');
        }
      });
    }
```

Emit  `triggerParentMethod` from your dialog:

```
this.sharedService.triggerParentMethod.next(true);
```

Complete [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lgorb6?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks! However can you provide short example to implement CRUD method (only the create function) which triggered from the input inside dialog window and then displayed on the parent page?

Comment: I didnt understand what you are trying to ask

Comment: What I meant is I have a `md-input` in the dialog window. Now I also want to create a CRUD method based on value entered on the `md-input` field. Any new object that is added then will be shown on the parent page.

Comment: that is a different question altogether! your original question has been answered which was related to calling a parent function from inside a dialog. Please upvote and mark accepted and open a new question for your second problem.